# mongoose.Model.updateOne doesn't work with nested property query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a simple api for blog application and have problem with updating/deleting single post with `updateOne()` and `deleteOne()` methods in mongoose Model.

The logic is very simple, find post by it's id which is passed in query params, and also additional requirement is that post's owner's id should be equal to id of current user which are passed in token and becomes available through middleware.

The test post document:

```
{
      "likes": 0,
      "dislikes": 0,
      "_id": "5c1a49464030141b3cc357c6",
      "owner": {
            "id": "5c1a49074030141b3cc357c5",
             "firstName": "John",
             "lastName": "Smith",
             "avatarSrc": "/profile-avatars/avatar1545226503543.jpg"
      },
      "title": ".....",
      "text": ".....",
      "previewSrc": "/post-previews/preview1545226565915.PNG",
      "__v": 0
}
```

Code which should update post:

```
router.put('/:id', authCheck, (req, res) => {
    Post.updateOne({_id: req.params.id, 'owner.id': req.userId}, req.body)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        });
});
```

Problem is in 'owner.id' query, the postId and userId are properly received but  the update doesn't occur.

Comment: Can I ask why are you querying by `_id` and `owner.id`? why not only by `_id`? this will actually run much slower. if  `_id` is unique then there wont be duplicate; therefore, you wont need to check if 2 properties are true.

Comment: @MuhandJumah
For authorization purposes. Only user who created certain post can edit him

Comment: I see, I would make `owner` an index otherwise this gives bad performance. Going back to your issue, the problem seems with `req.userId` can you do `console.log(req.userId)` and confirm the output?

Comment: @MuhandJumah
Yep, I checked it 10 times already, it's correct

Comment: I see, okay well we know 1 thing for sure a post cant have a different `owner`, or a different `_id` nor a different `__v` so can we change the update to not include those? just so we can come to a conclusion what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i find the problem:
These id strings are string objects, not simple string, to check it I:
1)First fetched post by it's id and then compared `owner.id` with `userId` in request, and find that they are not equal;
2)Compared strings with `equals` method and it returned true.

So problem could be solved this way:
1)Fetch post by it's id only;
2)Compare it's ids with `equals` method after post is fetched.

Comment: Thought of this but since your `owner` has the property as `id` and not `_id` I thought it was a custom `id` - Mark your answer correct :D

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, especially some properties wont change; not tested but would like to know the results

```
router.put('/:id', authCheck, (req, res) => {
    let updateObj = {
          likes: req.body.likes,
          dislikes: req.body.dislikes,
          title: req.body.title,
          text: req.body.text,
          previewSrc: req.previewSrc
    }
    Post.updateOne({_id: req.params.id, 'owner.id': req.userId}, updateObj)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            res.sendStatus(200);
        });
});
```